# Pair top-level key with nested value from jsonb document

Tags: postgresql, json, set-returning-functions, jsonb

Given the following data:

```
create table datas (id int, data jsonb);

insert into datas (id, data) 
values 
  (1, '{"key1": {"foo": "bar1","some":"thing1"}}'), 
  (2, '{"key2": {"foo": "bar2","some":"thing2"}}');
```

I've been able to extract the top level JSON as an array here given the following:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data)) AS keys;
```

Result:

```
[ "key1", "key2" ]
```

However, I'm looking to extract the following as columns and I'm having issue pairing a nested value with the top level JSON:

| Top Level JSON | Nested Value |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | bar1 |
| key2 | bar2 |

Could someone please recommend a way to access the sublevel data for each object and output it as per my example?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - issue was with my example not my actual data, sorry.  Corrected above.

Comment: Do you always want the value of the nested key `foo` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and [`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) should help. Details depend on possible input and desired outout.

Seems there is always at least one top-level key, and one nested value, and you want *one* result per table row.

For a **given** nested key (as per comment) it's even simpler. Say, the nested key is 'foo':

```
SELECT d0.key AS top_lvl_key, d0.value->>'foo' AS foo_value
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each (t.data) LIMIT 1) d0;
```

Else, to pick the "first" nested value:

```
SELECT d0.key AS top_lvl_key, d1.value AS lvl1_value
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each (t.data) LIMIT 1) d0
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(d0.value) LIMIT 1) d1;
```

`LIMIT 1` usually works to get the "first" element. To positively pick the "first" element (according to Postgres sort order) , use `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT d0.key AS top_lvl_key, d1.value AS lvl1_value
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each (t.data) WITH ORDINALITY) d0 ON d0.ordinality = 1
JOIN   LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(d0.value) WITH ORDINALITY) d1 ON d1.ordinality = 1;
```

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

To simply output all combinations of top-level keys and nested values - or if there is always exactly one:

```
SELECT d0.key AS lvl0, d1.value AS lvl1
FROM   tbl t, jsonb_each (t.data) d0, jsonb_each_text (d0.value) d1;
```

More variants:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CGZ7sDlE)

Comment: Thiis is awesome and definately helped me along.  `SELECT d0.key AS top_lvl_key, d1.value AS lvl1_value FROM tbl t CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each (t.data)) d0 JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(d0.value) WITH ORDINALITY) d1 ON d1.ordinality = 2;` gets me really close but I need to be able to select the level 1 key by name as the position changes depending on the data.  Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: @RMcLellan: A given key name only makes it simpler. See added query. If you know the outer key name as well, it gets simpler, yet ...

Answer (score 2):

If the nested key is known and you only have one top level key, you can also use a JSON path expression:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.keyvalue()') ->> 'key' as top_level_key,
       jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.*.foo') #>> '{}' as foo
from the_table
```

`jsonb_path_query_first()` returns a jsonb, the `#>> '{}'` is a hack to convert that to `text` as there is no easy or direct cast.

Comment: I assume this would only work if the top level key was uniform?  The issue I was running into is that my top level key was not (it's a date in my case).

Comment: @RMcLellan: the actual value of the top level key doesn't really matter. JSON only knows strings, numbers and booleans anyway (and keys can only be strings)

Comment: jsonb_path_query_first -> jsonb_path_query and it works great, thanks!